# How to unmarshal XML with HTML tags using JAXB

Tags: java, html, xml, jaxb

The XML content is like this:

```
<RichContent>
<Para>This is Paragraph 1
    <LineBreak/>
    <Strong>This is Strong html tag in Para1. </Strong>&#160;Something else...
</Para>
<Para>This is Paragraph 2
    <LineBreak/>
    <Strong>This is Strong html tag in Para2. </Strong>&#160;Something else...
</Para>
<Para>This is Paragraph 3
    <LineBreak/>
    <Strong>This is Strong html tag in Para3. </Strong>&#160;Something else...
</Para>
</RichContent>
```

The parsing class is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RichContent",  propOrder = {
    "para"
})
public class RichContent {

    @XmlElement(name = "Para")
    protected List<Para> para;

    // getter & setter
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Para", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
public static class Para {

    @XmlMixed
    protected List<String> content;

    public String getContent() {
        String result = "";
        for(String cnt : content) {
            result += cnt;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void setContent(List<String> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

I set the content with annotation "@XmlMixed", the "LineBreak" disappeared as I wished, but the problem is, the content between "Strong" and "/Strong" also disappeared.

Could anybody help me handle that? Thanks!

Comment: The `<strong>` tags are not closed. There should be a `</strong>` tag for each opening tag.

Comment: If the XML is supposed to contain free-form HTML (where there can be unclosed tags), it should be passed as CDATA or all special characters (`<`, `>`, `&`...) should be escaped.

Comment: @SamTyson Sorry coz changed some content, so missed the `/`, there's `</strong>` in the original xml.